# How to turn off camera capability on Android device programatically?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Can I use SDK for it, or its possible only from NDK?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply close camera then it might be done. But if you are willing to completely hack camera and make it useless then I don't think it can be done using SDK or NDK. It is native functionality you can not[should not] override it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm not prefer to say hack, just disable and enable later e.g. - that is part of my application, I believe I need to dig into drivers level, isn't it?

Comment: @Dima: yes its seems like you have to go for drivers.